# How to get the default id value from an href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code snippet where I dynamically create the input box:

```
 if (data != null) {
        locations = data;

        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            var newLineItem = domEditor.CreateElement({ type: "li" });
            var roomsLink = domEditor.CreateElement({ id: locations[i].Id, name: "locationRadioBtns", type: "a", href: "#", onclick: self.SelectLocation, innerHtml: locations[i].DisplayName, checked: i == 0, parent: $("#LocationRadioButtons") });
            $(newLineItem).append(roomsLink);
            $(LocationRadioButtons).append(newLineItem);

        }

        self.Display();
    }
```

Display method, I need to get the id of the first element created of the a href tag

```
this.Display = function () {

    console.log($('#locationRadioBtns').val(0)); //value of your default option

};
```

It comes back with undefined

Comment: check if yor locations object have data. Also you can check in browser if its getting generated in html by opening in developer tool. Which browser you are using.

Comment: what do you mean with "default id value"? An anchor-tag's href attribute has no default "id" or something. You should post the generated HTML and tell us what value exactly you want to access in the `Display` function

Comment: give some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `id`-attribute of the first element created by your loop?

try

```
console.log($('#locationRadioBtns a').first().attr('id'));
```

Comment: Thanks sumit. Do you know how I can get the value of the a tag that I have clicked?

Comment: If by "value" you mean the `href`'s value, then yes. You need to bind a click event.

`$('a.yourSelector').on('click', function(e) {var value = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');});`